# Wake-on-LAN functionality seems to not be working (even local port scan)

Tags: macos, wake-on-lan

I've enabled "Wake for network access" in my energy preferences. Then, I try to confirm that the UDP port is open:

```
$ sudo nmap -sU -p 9 127.0.0.1
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-06-10 01:36 CDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000079s latency).

PORT  STATE  SERVICE
9/udp closed discard
```

Is there something else I need to do to open up the WOL port?

Comment: Have you tried simply accessing it from another machine, empirical test?

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I tried.